# Declarative hyperlinking with Jersey and JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to use Jersey declarative hyperlinking and JAXB to achieve something that seems fairly simple to me, but despite reading all the docs and examples I could find I can't get things to work.

I have a bookstore with books, each of which has just a title.
I would like GET /bookstore to return just an array of hyperlinks to books, 
while GET /bookstore/some-title would return the actual serialized book attributes.

I am getting completely confused with resources and "representations", and with the way @Ref is supposed to work. What would be the cleanest way to design this?

The icing on the cake would be the ability to get either versions of the bookstore collection (shallow with just book URIs or deep with actual book attributes) based on a query parameter...

I have tried to add this method to bookstore:

```
@XmlElement
public BookRef[] getBookReferences()
{
    BookRef[] refs = new BookRef[_books.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) {
        refs[i] = new BookRef(_books.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    return refs;
}
```

with this BookRef class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="book")
public class BookRef
{
    private String _title;

    public BookRef()
    {
    }

    public BookRef(@PathParam("title") String title)
    {
        _title= title;
    }

    @Ref(resource=Book.class,
         style = Ref.Style.ABSOLUTE,
         bindings=@Binding(title="title", value="${instance.title}")
    )
    private URI _self;

    @XmlElement
    public URI getURI()
    {
        return _self;
    }
}
```

... but that just yields (in JSON): {"bookReferences":null}

Comment: Just at a glance, shouldn't `bindings=@Binding(title="title", value="${instance.title}")` use `name="title"` instead of `title="title"` ? Not that that would fix the underlying problem...